# Removing Embedded fonts from PdfPage

Tags: c#, fonts, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, embedded-fonts

I am using PdfSharp for generating PDFs. I have PDF templates which I load and import specific PdfPages from it in order to construct a PDF document filled with data. The templates have all static content, and in runtime I open the Pdf templates with import option, import the PdfPage needed and stamp dynamic content on it. Both static and dynamic printing involved Embedded fonts. Once this operation is completed in the resultant PDF document I see the Embedded fonts twice, thus increasing the size of the PDF document substantially.

How can I avoid this? I don't have much control over deciding which fonts to embed during the dynamic content printing operation.

I need to be able to remove the embedded fonts once I import the PdfPage from the template. Any points are appreciated. Basically we don't need duplicate embedded fonts in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp does not merge embedded fonts.

AFAIK the embedded fonts are only subsets containing the characters that are used. While it's very likely that some characters will be included twice (mainly in the A-Z and a-z range), this shouldn't be a real size problem. Merging the fonts is a very complicated task and not yet implemented.

Obviously it's better to have a single template file (with e.g. 100 pages) than 100 template files with only a single page when the final document consists of more than one template page.

Comment: Yes, I am already creating just 1 document containing 100s of pages, however now we have 2 sets of embedded subsets for each font as I import the page from the template on to the final document I am printing in runtime. I need to be able to say don't import the embdedded subsets that comes along with the page. Any ideas?